# Como fazer o clique do A ficar ativo para toda a LI

Tags: css

Tenho uma `li` com `a` dentro, e gostaria de ativar o clique do `a` para toda a `li`.
Ou seja, quando eu clicar no canto da `li` ele entre no link de qualquer forma, quero fazer isso sem Jquery.

Minha estrutura:

```css
.topo {
    width: 570px;
    margin-left: 95px;
    margin-top: 45px;
    float: left;
}
.topo > li {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 25px;
    position: relative;
}
.topo li span {
    font-family:'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 16px;
    color: #254261;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding-bottom: 8px;
}
.topo li:first-child {
    margin-left: 0px;
}
.topoBusca {
    background: url("../imagens/buscaTopo.png") no-repeat center;
    width: 41px;
    height: 42px;
    float: left;
}
.flechaSubmenu {
    background: url("../imagens/flechaSubmenu.png") no-repeat center;
    width: 8px;
    height: 5px;
    display: none;
    padding-top: 8px;
}
.topo li:hover .flechaSubmenu, .topo li:hover .subMenu {
    display: block;
    width: auto;
}
.subMenu {
    width: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    padding-top: 21px;
}
.subMenu li {
    width: 200px;
    height: 42px;
    padding-left: 25px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #dddedf;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    font-family:"Titillium Web", sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 42px;
    color: #7E7E7E;
    font-style: normal;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.subMenu li:hover {
    color: #254261;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #f7bb57;
}
```

```html
<ul class="topo">
    <li> <span>Home</span>

        <div class="flechaSubmenu"></div>
        <ul class="subMenu">
            <li> <a href="/analise-de-riscos">Análise de Risco</a>

            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove o `width` e o `padding-left` de `.subMenu li` e passa essas propriedades para o link, adicionando também um `display: block`:

```
.subMenu li a {
    display: block;
    width: 200px;
    padding-left: 25px;
}
```

Ficando assim:

```css
.topo {
    width: 570px;
    margin-left: 95px;
    margin-top: 45px;
    float: left;
}
.topo > li {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 25px;
    position: relative;
}
.topo li span {
    font-family:'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 16px;
    color: #254261;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding-bottom: 8px;
}
.topo li:first-child {
    margin-left: 0px;
}
.topoBusca {
    background: url("../imagens/buscaTopo.png") no-repeat center;
    width: 41px;
    height: 42px;
    float: left;
}
.flechaSubmenu {
    background: url("../imagens/flechaSubmenu.png") no-repeat center;
    width: 8px;
    height: 5px;
    display: none;
    padding-top: 8px;
}
.topo li:hover .flechaSubmenu, .topo li:hover .subMenu {
    display: block;
    width: auto;
}
.subMenu {
    width: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    padding-top: 21px;
}
.subMenu li {
    height: 42px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #dddedf;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    font-family:"Titillium Web", sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 42px;
    color: #7E7E7E;
    font-style: normal;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.subMenu li a {
    display: block;
    width: 200px;
    padding-left: 25px;
}
.subMenu li:hover {
    color: #254261;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #f7bb57;
}
```

```html
<ul class="topo">
    <li> <span>Home</span>

        <div class="flechaSubmenu"></div>
        <ul class="subMenu">
            <li> <a href="/analise-de-riscos">Análise de Risco</a>

            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Resposta perfeita, valeu!

Answer (score 2):

Eu recomendaria utilizar o `display: inline-block` na tag `a` isso faz com que ele preencha toda a `li`, assim tudo que você clicar dentro `li` abrirá o link (tag `a`)

ex:

```css
ul{
  padding: 0px;
  list-style:none;
}

ul li a{
  background: #DDD;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 3px 10px;
}

ul li a:hover{
  background: #464646;
  color: white;
}

.menu-2 li{
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<h2> Menu 1</h2>
<ul class="menu-1">
  <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
</ul>
<h2> Menu 2</h2>

<ul class="menu-2">
  <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

Mas lembre-se, coloque o `padding`, `margin` ou `width` e `height` se for usar, dentro da tag `a` pois é ela que tem que preencher a tag `li` com no exemplo.